GitHub Actions upload-artifact@v4.4.0 Path Patterns Not Working After Upgrade
I recently upgraded from actions/upload-artifact@v3 to actions/upload-artifact@v4.4.0 in my GitHub Actions workflow, and I'm encountering issues with the path patterns for uploading artifacts. The patterns that worked in the previous version no longer seem to work with the upgraded version. Here’s the configuration I am using:
Currently I am facing issue which those files not picking up and I have seen only plan.txt inside artifacts, how to regerate those patterns ??
Old version:
- name: "Upload Artifacts Plan files"
  uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
  if: failure() || success()
  with:
    name: terragrunt-plan
    retention-days: 7
    path: |
      **/*.tfplan
      **/plan.txt
      **/.terraform.lock.hcl

New version:
- name: "Upload Artifacts Plan files"
  uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4.4.0
  if: failure() || success()
  with:
    name: terragrunt-plan
    retention-days: 7
    overwrite: true
    path: |
      ${{ github.workspace }}/.terragrunt-download/**/**/*.tfplan
      ${{ github.workspace }}/.terragrunt-download/**/**/*.terraform.lock.hcl
      **/plan.txt
      ${{ github.workspace }}/**/**/.terraform.lock.hcl
      ${{ github.workspace }}/**/.terraform.lock.hcl


What is your question? A major version change tells you there may be breaking changes, and there are various links on e.g. https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact/releases/tag/v4.0.0 explaining the details.

Do you need include-hidden-files? There was a change that came into effect today. https://github.blog/changelog/2024-08-19-notice-of-upcoming-deprecations-and-breaking-changes-in-github-actions-runners/

4.4 introduced a breaking change to combat potential security issues, causing it to ignore any "hidden files", this includes any files contained in a folder starting with a .. Thus, anything under .terragrunt-download is considered a hidden file. As @BenjaminW mentions, there is a new setting to include these folders explicitly.
Be careful though reason this was introduced, is that these folders may contain sensitive configuration like access tokens, keys and secrets.

Or, if you have control over the foldername, rename it to terragrunt-download instead.

Also my workflow is two, artifacts name is same two workflow executed then all the artifacts appended in same artifacts. But new version is not supporting, Is there anyway to upload in the same artifact name?

@Shankar That's a separate question.
